# How to find the altitude of a right triangle given angles and a sum of their sides?

Tags: euclidean-geometry

The problem is as follows:

> In the figure it is known $VN=NA$ and $AH+HM=MV$ and $VA=10\,cm$. Using this information find $AH$.

[image: Sketch of the problem]

The choices given in my book are:

$\begin{array}{cc}
1.&\textrm{6 cm}\\
2.&\textrm{7 cm}\\
3.&\textrm{8 cm}\\
4.&\textrm{5 cm}\\
5.&\textrm{4 cm}\\
\end{array}$

According to the answers sheet the answer is choice 4.

I really don't know how to solve this problem. Is there a way to solve it using congruence or some sort of construction?.

A while ago I posted a [similar problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3916522/how-to-find-the-angle-formed-by-a-cevian-in-a-right-triangle-given-a-condition/3920496#3920496) to this and I attempted to use that strategy but it didn't work for that problem.

Thus how to solve this using only euclidean geometry constructions?. Comparing with known triangles it can be allowed.

I tried looking for which lines to draw but I couldn't find the right one. Therefore can someone help me here please?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]
Let's draw a perpendicular line from the point $N$ to the line segment $VH$ and call its intersection with $VH$ $P$. Since $VN=NA$, $NP$ is the middle base. Accordingly, let $2NP=AH=2m$ and $HM=n$. So $VP=PH=m+n$ since $VM=2m+n$ and $NP$ is the middle base. The problem is now solved.
$$PM=(m+n)-n=m,$$
$$NP=PM \Longrightarrow 3\alpha=45^{\circ},$$
$$3\alpha=45^{\circ} \Longrightarrow 2\alpha=30^{\circ},$$
$$2\times 2m =VA=10 \ (\text{According to the 30-60-90 triangle}) \Longrightarrow 2m=AH=5.$$

Comment: I recommend adding in your answer that $PM=m$ because you are using the information given as, $AH+HM=MV$. I called $PM=g$, then $AH=2m$, $HM=n$ and $MV=PM+PV$, as $MV=g+(g+n)$, then $2m+n=2g+n$, therefore $g=m$ so $PM=m$, and this solves the problem as $PM=PN$ and as it is a right triangle it follows your instructions. This will make your answer more easy to understand.

Comment: By the way, can you help me [with this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4476968/how-to-find-the-angle-made-by-isosceles-triangles-on-the-interior-of-a-kite) is it possible to solve that without using triangle similarity?. Maybe does it exist some construction?. Overall thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you also [help me here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4477741/how-to-find-an-angle-in-the-corner-of-an-isosceles-triangle) I am still stuck on that problem. I will appreciate your help.